# Desktop Version of Google's Annotated Time Line Component?

Tags: c#, java, c++, wpf, google-visualization

I've been using [Google's Annotated Time Line Visualization component](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) for the last couple of weeks and I love it! I've been able to make plots with about 10k points without much trouble.

Do you know of a desktop component I could plug into my application that delivers the same WOW factor that Google's component does? I don't care what the language/toolkit is. I prefer C#,Java,Ruby,C++ or Python... (in that order) however any other's would apply. I also prefer it to be free and open source, but if it's not that's OK as well.

Thanks for your time!

Note: This doesn't have to be cross-platform. Windows is fine.

Edit (2009-08-07):

Even if I can only plot 10k points, I am fine with that. I would just like a desktop control that delivers the same "wow" factor and works in a similar manner (zooming, scrolling, annotations, etc) that the Google component does.

Edit (2009-09-03):

I really prefer the language to be C#. I started a bounty to see if anyone can find some good ones. I want it to be almost identical to Google's Annotated Timeline Component. I would use Google's Component, but I want a desktop component... and I don't want to run into performance limitations because of the browser. Using Adobe Air is out of the question.

Edit (2009-09-03):

Do not recommend Visifire. I have evaluated it, and it doesn't support zooming. Remember, it must be very close to Google's component in terms of functionality and "wow" factor.

Comment: I see that MS released a new WPF build with charting included. It doesn't look as nice as the Google Visualization Component, but it may get the job done. I would love to read others experiences with these components as well. http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117

Answer (score 1):

This WPF-based chart control at codeproject may put you in the right direction.  It's got smooth panning/zooming/scrolling :

[WPF Chart Control With Pan, Zoom and More By John Stewien](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/swordfishcharts.aspx)

If you're needing to plot *millions* of points, you're going to run into performance issues quickly if the control doesn't have a mechanism for loading/sampling only what it needs to display.  Even then, that's a very large number of data point to want to access in one control.

Answer (score 0):

Hm i am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but for java there is the very good library [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) which is not exactly as interactive as the one you mentioned but it is really easy to use and pretty flexible for you to subclass and tweak to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/screenshots.html).  It's a python based library, however it's very flexible in that it can take it's input from a variety of sources.

An alternative is to embed a web browser control in you wpf application.  You'll probably need access to the DOM, so you might have to use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28VS.80%29.aspx) in a WinForm.  A good article descibing how this is done can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dditweb/archive/2007/08/22/using-virtual-earth-in-your-wpf-application.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft also has free chart control you can get at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en. It's pretty good--especially for being free.

I have used [Dundas](http://dundas.com) charts in the past. They are excellent but pricey. There are several other vendors with good chart controls including [DotNetCharting](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/), [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chart.aspx), Component Art, and Infragistics.